# rufus 4.3 damage USB

Tags: usb, rufus

I just got rufus 4.3 and I am 0-4 and all 4 USB drives seem to be bricked. They are recognized but have no file format, which ok then I can format, but then it is unable to determine capacity for the devices. 3 PNY 32GB drives and a Microcenter one.

Comment: Rufus should not be able to stop a drive size from being recognised.  Did the drives need to be repartitioned maybe?

Comment: @davidgo This is probably one of those cases where users don't understand what's happening: After "burning" e.g. a Linux installation/live ISO the resulting partitioning & file system(s) are indeed unrecognizable in Windows - no letter assigned - therefore users wrongly assume the stick became defective (and then blame the tool - Rufus in this case - for something totally expected).

Comment: To the author: If the aforementioned situation rings a bell then please check Drive Management before anything else where you should find the USB stick as usual. Then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/initialize-new-disks or use `diskpart` in command prompt.

Answer (score -1):

Rufus 4.3, unlike previous versions was attempting to make a change to windows somehow (I did not really read the warning in windows security). I allowed it and it started working fine. Not sure what was in there but I never experienced this issue with previous versions